# How to set condition to True?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I've created a program that uses pyautogui to locate an image stored in the directory and click on it when it finds it. So when it sees 'Microsoft Edge' it instantly clicks on it. I have this running on a loop and want to stop the loop when it finds the image. This is really important for me—but I want the loop to stop even before it clicks it, so while 'double' is False, as you will see below.

Here it is:

```
import pyautogui as p
import time
import random
import os
import pygame
from hashlib import sha256

def search(query):
    p.hotkey("ctrl","e")
    time.sleep(.1)
    p.write(query)
    p.press("enter")
    time.sleep(.67)

def imageFind(image,g,double):
    a = 0
    b = 0
    while(a==0 and b==0):
        try:
            a,b = p.locateCenterOnScreen(image,grayscale=g)
        except TypeError:
            pass

    if double == True:
        p.doubleClick(a,b)
    else:
        p.click(a,b)

    return a,b

#p.hotkey("win","d")
counter = 1
while counter == 1:
    image_find = imageFind("Edge.png",False,False)
    if image_find == True:
        imageFind("Edge.png",False,True)
        counter = 0
```

I've done `if image_find == True` but it doesn't work as the loop continues.

So how do I code this so that when it finds the image, it stops. How do confirm that what it finds is a True statement?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to return `False` if it doesn't find it. Instead of the coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`imageFind` does not return a single bool values but instead returns a tuple. your `True` condition is when both `a` and `b` are non zero so change your `if image_find == True:` to `if all(image_find):`

`all()` returns `True` only if all values are `True` or non zero

Comment: One more thing. I've implemented your answer but it doesn't click on Microsoft Edge straight away. It's always after I've clicked somewhere else does it finally move to it and click it, therefore meaning it doesn't break the loop on the first try. What's wrong with my code that is causing that?

Comment: @theshape try replacing `imageFind("Edge.png",False,True)` with `p.doubleClick(*image_find)`

Answer (score 0):

Or try to check if the minimum is nonzero:

```
if min(image_find):
```